# Build yara static lib with a musl-gcc for rust project

Tags: lib, musl, yara

I am trying to build yara static lib with a musl-gcc for my rust project. But when it is running

```
CC="musl-gcc"  \
    CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/musl/include -I/usr/include/linux -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-musl"  \
    LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/musl/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl"  \
    ./configure \
      --with-crypto \
        --enable-magic \
        --enable-cuckoo \
        --enable-dotnet
```

it return me error "configure: error: pthread API support is required". Details output

```
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work with -mthreads... no
checking for the pthreads library -lpthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with --thread-safe... no
checking whether pthreads work with -mt... no
checking for pthread-config... no
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ekidd/rust-musl-builder
USER root

ENV JANSSON_VERSION 2.14
ENV YARA_VERSION 4.3.1

RUN apt-get update

RUN cd /tmp \
    && curl -LO https://github.com/akheron/jansson/releases/download/v2.14/jansson-${JANSSON_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar -zxf jansson-${JANSSON_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && cd /tmp/jansson-$JANSSON_VERSION \
    && CC="musl-gcc" CFLAGS="-fPIC" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/musl --host=x86_64-linux-musl --disable-shared \
    && make \
    && make check \
    && make install \
    && cd /tmp \
    && rm -r jansson-$JANSSON_VERSION

RUN cd /tmp \
    && curl -LO https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara/archive/refs/tags/v${YARA_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar -zxf v${YARA_VERSION}.tar.gz

WORKDIR /tmp/yara-$YARA_VERSION

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmagic-dev \
    automake \
    libtool \
    autoconf

RUN ./bootstrap.sh \
    && CC="musl-gcc"  \
    CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/musl/include -I/usr/include/linux -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-musl"  \
    LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/musl/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl"  \
    ./configure \
      --with-crypto \
        --enable-magic \
        --enable-cuckoo \
        --enable-dotnet  \
    && sudo make depend \
    && sudo make -j$(nproc) \
    && sudo make install \
    && rm -r /tmp/yara-$YARA_VERSION
```

I tried add path pthread header to CFLAGS and add path pthread static lib to LDFLAGS but it did not help

About CFLAGS:
/usr/local/musl/include - path to jansson headers
/usr/include/linux - path to libmagic headers
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-musl - path to pthread header (it did not help )

About LDFLAGS:
/usr/local/musl/lib - path to jansson static lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu - path to libmagic static lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl - path to pthread static lib (it also did not help )

docker build command:  docker build . -f ./Dockerfile -t yara-build-image:latest